# Lotusscript : How to sort the field values (an array of words) by their frequency

Tags: sorting, frequency, lotusscript

I would like to sort the field values (strings) by their frequency in lotusscript.
Has anyone an idea to solve this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What did you try? This is not a platform for complete solutions, but for helping you with your own specific problems. Please show us, which effort you made to solve the problem on your own, that makes it more likely for someone to answer your question...

Comment: Just to give you a little help for the start: [Here](http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Counting-unique-elements-in-a-text-list) is a cool way to do it in Formula... Of course this does not at all work in LotusScript, but it still is cool ;)

Comment: I don't think you have asked the question clearly. I suspect Simon and Torsten both misunderstood what you want. Is it that you have one multivalued field, in one document, that contains a list of words which have some duplicates, and you want to sort the values not alphabetically but based on how many duplicates there are, so that the list c,d,b,a,a,b,a,a is re-sorted a,a,a,a,b,b,c,d?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would avoid LotusScript if you can help it. You are going to run into [limitations](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_APPENDIX_A_LANGUAGE_AND_SCRIPT_LIMITS.html) that cannot be worked around.

Regardless of which route you do take, from a performance point of view it is better to have the View indexes do the work.

So you would create a view. The first column would be as follows.

- Column Value:  The field you want to check.
- Sort: Ascending
- Type: Categorized

After this you can access the data using the [NotesViewNavigator](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESVIEWNAVIGATOR_CLASS.html). The related method call is [getNextCategory](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLES_GETNEXTCATEGORY_METHOD_EX_VIEWNAV.html). This will give you a view entry object which you can call ChildCount on to get totals.

For example (Disclaimer: Code written from memory, not guaranteed to run):

```
Dim sess As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim vw As NotesView
Dim nav as NotesViewNavigator
Dim entryA As NotesViewEntry
Dim entryB As NotesViewEntry    

Set db = sess.CurrentDatabase

Set vw = db.GetView("testView")

vw.AutoUpdate = False

Set nav = vw.CreateViewNav

Set entryA = nav.GetFirst
while entryA not Nothing 
    Set entryB = nav.GetNextCategory(entryA)
    if entryB not nothing then 

        ' Do your processing. 
        ' entryB.childCount will give total.

    end if

    set EntryA = EntryB

Wend

view.AutoUpdate = True
```

This way the heavy lifting (string sorting, counting) is handled by the View index. So you only need to process the final results.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the op's (old) question directly, the way to do this in LotusScript is both simple and easy:

```
dim para as string
dim words as variant
dim fq list as long

'get the text to freq-count
para = doc.text '(or $ from somewhere)
'tidy up para by removing/replacing characters you don't want
para = replace(para, split(". , : ; - [ ] ()"), "")
words = split(para) 'or split(words, "delim") - default is space
forall w in words
if iselement(words(w)) then
   fq(w) = fq(w) + 1
Else
   fq(w) = 1
End forall
'you now have a count of each individual word in the FQ list

'to get the words out and the word frequencies (not sorted):
forall x in fq
   print listtag(x) = x
End forall
```

Thats it. No issue with LotusScript - quick and easy (and lists can be massive). To get a sorted list, you would have to move to an array and do a sort on it or move to a field and let @sort do the job somehow.